# Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: android, build.gradle

Android Studio is giving this error while compiling the project. I have searched and found that this may happen because of

> android

Block in top of the build.gradle.But in my build.gradle it may be not the problem.
here is my gradle files.

build.gradle

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to     all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
 repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
}
dependencies {
```

}

app.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
  compileSdkVersion 20
  buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ptrprograms.chromecast"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
 }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:19.0.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```

}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're using Gradle domain-specific language (DSL) defined in the Android plugin before applying that plugin.

Remove the

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
}
```

in your top-level build.gradle. You already have `compileSdkVersion 20` in your app build.gradle file where it actually matters.

> now its showing "Error:(16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'

`runProguard` was renamed to `minifyEnabled` in the Android Gradle plugin some time ago. You should rename it in your build script as well.

Comment: now its working..i have clean the project once again and rebuild it.thank you laalto

Answer (score 1):

Not Solved:
I'm using gradle-experimental for doing NDK stuff.

Error:(13, 0) Dexcount plugin requires the Android plugin to be configured
MY Top level build.gradle file:

buildscript {

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
}
```

}

allprojects {

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

}