# Error(19,0) Gradle DSL method not found: android()

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I just **upgraded android studio** and the previously compiled project is now showing **errors!**

> Error(19,0) Gradle DSL method not found: android()

, Here is the build script and app.build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

   android {
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
productFlavors {
}
  }

 dependencies {
}
```

and here is the build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aqsa.personal.newpro"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

   dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

Comment: remove everything after `allprojects` section of your application build.gradle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here is the build script and app.build.gradle

Remove everything after the `allprojects` closure out of the top-level `build.gradle` file, leaving you with:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
  }
    allprojects {
      repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

The `android` closure, in particular, needs to be in a module that is using one of the Gradle for Android plugins (e.g., `com.android.application`).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this from the first code

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913502/error19-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android)

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

> Error:(19, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

**Solution :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Remove after allprojects code, and build project.this solution works for me.